# How to properly throw an array in a try...catch block in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want the logging function below to accept single, or array objects as a named parameter or from the pipeline. I seem to have it working, but if I try to throw an array to the function from a `try...catch` block it treats it all as a single string concatenated together.

Here is my function:

```
function log {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)][object[]]$msg,
        [ValidateSet("FATAL", "ERROR", "WARN", "INFO", "DEBUG")]
            [string]$level = "INFO",
        [switch]$quiet
    )
    
    process
    {
        $msg | ForEach-Object {
            $out = "[$((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("u"))] $($level.ToUpper()) $_"
            if ($quiet) { $out | Out-File -FilePath $logpath -Append } else { $out | Tee-Object -FilePath $logpath -Append }
        }
    }
}
```

I can do something like this:

```
try {
    $a = @("Test", "Test2")
    $a | log
    throw $a
}
catch {
    $_ | log
    exit 1
}
```

And get the following output:

```
[2023-09-19 20:04:46Z] INFO Test
[2023-09-19 20:04:48Z] INFO Test2
[2023-09-19 20:04:50Z] INFO Test Test2
```

I've tried everything I can think of, and it always converts it to a single string.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `throw` doesn't pass the object as is. Instead it wraps it in a `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0

So, I changed my code to:

```
try {
    $a = @("Test", "Test2")
    $a | log
    throw $a
}
catch {
    $_.TargetObject | log
    exit 1
}
```

And now I get:

```
[2023-09-19 20:20:49Z] INFO Test
[2023-09-19 20:20:51Z] INFO Test2
[2023-09-19 20:20:52Z] INFO Test
[2023-09-19 20:20:54Z] INFO Test2
```